# How to declare a C-array in header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I have a C-array of `CGPoint` that I want to declare in the header file .h.

```
CGPoint checkPoint[8];
```

But when I try to give it a value in .m:

```
checkPoint[8] = { //<-- Error Here
    CGPointMake(0, -10),
    CGPointMake(10, 0),
    CGPointMake(0, 10),
    CGPointMake(-10, 0),
    CGPointMake(-10, -10),
    CGPointMake(10, -10),
    CGPointMake(10, 10),
    CGPointMake(-10, 10)
};
```

It gives me an error pointing at the first opening bracket: Expected expression

Im not very used with C-arrays, how is the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I have tried with `extern` in the header file, but I get this error message: Type name does not allow storage class to be specified.

Comment: Please show the section of the header where you declare `extern CGPoint checkPoint[8];` It must be done outside any type / interface declaration, otherwise `extern` would not be valid.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that it had to be outside of the @interface, I don't get that error anymore, but I still get the error when I try giving it a value.

Comment: That too needs to be outside any `@implementation` block in a .m file, and it may not call `CGPointMake`.

Comment: xD Im so unused to these types of arrays. Thanks man it works like I want now, I accept your answer and you can add that it needs to be outside of the interface and implementation so other people can find it faster ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `extern` to the declaration in the header:

```
extern CGPoint checkPoint[8];
```

This would make it a declaration, rather than a declaration/definition. Note that the definition wouldn't compile because of calls to `CGPointMake` in the initializer (must be compile-time constant, but `CGPointMake` is a function).

You can replace `CGPointMake` with `{.x= 0, .y=-10}` style of initializer, like this:

```
checkPoint[8] = { //<-- Error Here
    {.x=0,   .y=-10},
    {.x=10,  .y=0},
    {.x=0,   .y=10},
    {.x=-10, .y=0},
    {.x=-10, .y=-10},
    {.x=10,  .y=-10},
    {.x=10,  .y=10},
    {.x=-10, .y=10}
};
```

**Note :** (in response to a thread of comments to question)

`extern` is used for declaring global variables. They do not belong to any class, so their declaration needs to be outside an `@interface`, and their definition needs to be outside the `@implementation` block.

Comment: I've tried that already, sorry for not including it in the question, when I use the extern I get an error message: Type name does not allow storage class to be specified.

Comment: @Arbitur Are you trying to declare the extern variable as an instance variable for a class?  There are four or five SO questions relating to that error message and they all relate to putting `extern` or `static` on an instance variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as `extern CGPoint checkPoint[8]` in the header, and then in *one* source file you can initialise it as `CGPoint checkPoint[8] = { { 0.0f, -10.0f }, { 10.0f, 0.0f }, … };`

Without the `extern` you would be defining it anew in every file that includes the header. The initialisers also need to be compile-time constants.